How to get inputStream as return value from ServerHttpRequest in spring reactive?
I am writing a Spring Reactive implementation for a third-party SPI which is based on a traditional servlet. One method requires InputStream from request as return value:
/**
 * Returns the request input stream
 *
 * @param buffered if the input stream should be buffered and support for multiple reads
 * @return the request input stream
 */
 InputStream getInputStream(boolean buffered);

This is my implements:
private InputStream inputStream;

private ServerHttpRequest request;

@Override
public InputStream getInputStream(boolean buffered) {
  if (inputStream != null) {
    return inputStream;
  }

  var inputStreamMono =
      request
          .getBody()
          .collect(
              InputStreamCollector::new,
              (t, dataBuffer) -> t.collectInputStream(dataBuffer.asInputStream()))
          .flatMap(inputStreamCollector -> Mono.just(inputStreamCollector.getInputStream()));

  if (buffered) {
    return inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStreamMono.block()));
  }

  return inputStreamMono.block();
}

public class InputStreamCollector {
  private InputStream is;

  public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return this.is;
  }

  public void collectInputStream(InputStream is) {
    if (this.is == null) this.is = is;
    this.is = new SequenceInputStream(this.is, is);
  }
}

But it receives below exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-2
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/linkerp/manager" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1779) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at org.umbrella.ReactiveHttpRequest.getInputStream(ReactiveHttpRequest.java:85) ~[classes/:na]

Is there anything I missed? Or is there a proper way to return InputStream from a reactive ServerHttpRequest?

This solution works, the key point is using Mono.toFuture().get() to return InputStream synchronously
private final ServerHttpRequest request;
private InputStream inputStream;

@Override
public InputStream getInputStream(boolean buffered) {
  if (inputStream != null) {
    return inputStream;
  }
  try {
    var streams =
        request.getBody().collectList().toFuture().get().stream()
            .map(DataBuffer::asInputStream)
            .toList();
    var sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));
    return buffered ? inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(sequenceInputStream) : sequenceInputStream;
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

